# Adding IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly permission in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have the following model -

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    clubs = models.ManyToManyField(Club,related_name = 'people')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

used to create a rest api.

`views.py`

```
class PersonDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        person_id = self.kwargs.get('pk',None)
        return Person.objects.get(pk=person_id)
```

How do I add permissions so that only authenticated user can add,update delete or retrieve objects from the person list in the api. And read-only permissions for non authorized users. I tried going through the docs but it is all very confusing. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **add [`IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly) permission class** to `PersonDetail` view.

From the DRF [Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly):

> The `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` will allow authenticated users to perform any request. Requests for unauthorised users will only be permitted if the request
>   method is one of the "safe" methods; `GET`, `HEAD` or `OPTIONS`.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly


class PersonDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,) # specify the permission class in your view

    def get_object(self):
        person_id = self.kwargs.get('pk',None)
        return Person.objects.get(pk=person_id)
```

Comment: That doesn't do it. I can still delete as anonymous user.

Comment: Please check again because it only allows `GET`, `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` request for anonymous users and not `DELETE` request. Here is official docs [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly)